# Why isn't the starts with, ends with regularexpression working on C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Why isn't my regular expression finding my string?

```
 Regex.Replace(" SCRIPT language=Javascript src=\"\"\r\ntype=text/javascript ",
    "^language=Javascript$",
    "language=\"Javascript\"",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled
);
```

the `^language=Javascript$` isn't working. if I remove it it works, but I want to make sure that a partially similar string doesn't get replaced (it has happened in my tests). The strings are not constants, I actually using variables, but this is just 1 case that I am using. Any help?

Comment: In what sense is `language` at the *beginning* of `SCRIPT language=`

Comment: Your string does not start and end with that expression.

Comment: @mellamokb I don't understand what you mean? The issues is not if the string is proper html or not, if that's what you're referring to. This is only an example case in my tests

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is because `^` represents the *start of the string* and `$` the *end of the string*. Your regex simply cannot match. You could use

```
\blanguage=Javascript\b
```

as a workaround if you just want to make sure that `foolanguage=Javascript` doesn't match. But that depends a little on the data you expect and stuff into that method. A safer way would be

```
(?<= )language=Javascript(?= )
```

which would make sure that there is a space before and after the match. You can make it more complex (and reliable) from there, e.g.

```
(?<= )language=Javascript(?= |>)
```

to match even `<script type='text/javascript' language=Javascript>`.

Comment: I had something similar before, but I have found that there is a case (happened last night) that there might be line breaks. I could remove linebreaks, but I figured this could be faster, but \bstring\b would not work if its says \bmyAttribute=http://www.google.com\?lang=&\b

Comment: As usual with regexes: Know what your inputs are and can be and what exactly you want and need. There isn't going to be a one-size-fits-all answer for such sort of a problem. Especially not if you only give scarce details. I gave you a starting point. Working from there is up to you. I cannot really do more.

Comment: I catch your drift. Actually checking out your edit, this works along with something else that came to mind. thank you so much.